# Cannot coverage phpunit report to html

Tags: phpunit, laravel-testing

when i run this command:

> ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html testResult

it is runing, but export an error:

> No code coverage driver is available

and this is php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t.%p"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="E:\wamp64\tmp"
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
```

I dont know what is my problem. please help

Comment: What is your output from `php -v` on the command line? It's entirely possible that it's using a different php than the one you're configuring

Comment: i dont know why but when i use zend_extension = "E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll", myphpadmin cant access. And when i change xampp server, it is work